# Image selection input in html with checkbox or radio

Tags: html, image, checkbox, radio-button

I'm creating a web page and I want to create a section with images so the user can select only one by clicking on it. I'm trying with checkbox and radio but it only gets selected when I press on the checkbox itself, not in the image. How can I do that?

I've tried this:

```
<section>
        <fieldset>
                <legend><h2>Favorite character</h2></legend>
    
                <input type="checkbox" id="imagen">
                <label for="imagen"><img src="image.jpg"></label>
        </fieldset>
</section>
```

And also the same but with radio

Comment: The `for` attribute in your label tag should match the `id` of your input

Answer (score 0):

```html
<section>
        <fieldset>
                <legend><h2>Favorite character</h2></legend>
    
                <input type="checkbox" id="imagen">
                <label for="imagen"><img src="image.jpg"></label>
        </fieldset>
</section>
```

You have to give the same name to the for of label as you gave to the id of your input.
Apply this in your code and it will work.

Comment: ups... well but I changed it and I still can't select the input through the image, still just trough the input itself